# Android SavedState

Tags: android, android-intent

I have tried every way possible to use SaveState in a prior post I was instructed to use finish() or use onBackPressed ok that saves the data on the MainActivity but I would like to understand how to use Bundle savedInstanceState below is my code arrangment Please comment what is wrong and offer suggested fixes My goal is to only restore one value in one of the EditText fields?
Yes I have looked at Adroid Developer and numerous other quality sites

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnAdd;
Button brnNext;

EditText ETinput;
EditText ETans;

float X = (float) 10.0;
public final static String EXTRA = "com.dwight.thebigtest.pagetwo.MESSAGE";
public int sVarA;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    savedInstanceState.putInt("sVarA",sVarA);

    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    brnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    ETans = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ETans);
    ETinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ETinput);
    addListenerOnButton_ADD();
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle InState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(InState);
    if(InState != null) {
        sVarA = InState.getInt("sVarA");
        ETans.setText(String.valueOf(sVarA));
    }
}

private void addListenerOnButton_ADD(){
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            float Y = Float.valueOf(ETinput.getText().toString().trim());
            float Z = Y + X;

            ETans.setText(String.valueOf(Z));
        }
    });
}

    public void sendNext(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PageTwo.class);
            String message = ETans.getText().toString().trim();

            intent.putExtra(EXTRA,message);
            startActivity(intent);

    }
```

}

This code makes the trip back from the secondActivity

```
    private void addListenerOnButton_Back(){
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(PageTwo.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            //onBackPressed();// Less Screen Flash
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This snippet caught my eye:

```
Intent i = new Intent(PageTwo.this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
//onBackPressed();// Less Screen Flash
```

You're making a new Intent to return to the MainActivity, but instead, it creates a new instance of MainActivity which is then added to the activity stack. When the new MainActivity is created, it has NO savedInstanceState: it's brand new.

`onBackPressed` and `finish` are the appropriate ways of finishing the current activity and returning to the previous one.

The purpose of `savedInstanceState` is to restore the state of an activity when it is destroyed by the system (for instance, due to lack of memory). If you simply return to the previous activity via the back button, `savedInstanceState` is not used because the activity is still in memory. No need to restore it.

If you enable "Don't keep activities" in your phone/emulator's Developer Options, Android will force-stop activities once abandoned. So when PageTwo is created and shown, since MainActivity is no longer in the foreground, it will be destroyed. This is where the instance state is saved. When you return to the same MainActivity (pressing back), the activity must be recreated using that instance state.

For more information, research about [Android's activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Comment: so if I want to return a new or old value to the MainActivity screen from PageTwo Activity I would use the putEXTRA concept on PageTwo Activity before the onBackPressed ? The real goal her was to pass values to multiple screens from Various screens

Comment: If you want MainActivity to send data to PageTwo, you can use Intent extras. If you want PageTwo to send data to MainActivity, you have to start PageTwo with startActivityForResult, then setResult and finish in PageTwo.

Comment: So I would use startActivityForResult in place of onCreate OR use startActivityForTesult in the Button Back listener with the value to return set equat to setResult = "string" or = int 100 ? I think I can construct the code just not sure wher to place it on PageTwo and how to get it on MainActivity

Comment: OK got it I can pass a value back from PageTwo still not real clear on how to use or when to use instance state I do have some understanding of life cycle It seems that instance state is so the limited memory Android device can be overidden due to its limited memor it destroys more than a desktop computer